# Windows 7: How to disable overlapping tabs in taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

How can I get rid of this really annoying behaviour in Windows 7 (I also had this problem with some Linux distributions):

[image: Tabs of the same app are grouped together]

I do not want tabs of the same program to be grouped together, as it always requires an additional click to go to the correct window. Does anybody know a possibility to turn this of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: “Taskbar and Start Menu Properties” window]

Right-click on an empty space in the taskbar. Then click “Properties” in the menu that pops up. In the “Taskbar and Start Menu Properties” window open the “Taskbar” tab find the “Taskbar buttons” option, choose “Never combine” and click on “OK”.

But then labels will be shown. [This article](https://www.ghacks.net/2014/08/12/modify-the-windows-taskbar-to-show-icons-for-each-program-instance-individually/) shows how to hide them.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on free space on taskbar, choose Properties -> Taskbar buttons -> Never combine.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the taskbar settings that's called 'Combine taskbar buttons'. Set that to 'Never' and your programs' windows won't group together anymore.